# Subcategorisation Frame with DPs

Tags: syntax, english, lexicon, x-bar-theory, determiners

I want to construct a subcatagorisation frame for some words, for example that take a DP complement. Take the preposition "between" as example. I arrive at this point:

```
                     Form: "between"
                     Subcategorisation frame: [p'____DP]
```

However, I wish to list out the features of the NP which is dominated by the DP complement to the preposition "between". The NP's features may include that the NP should be plural. Could anyone here tell me how I can include this piece of information in the given frame?

I have come up with one but am not certain if it is right:

```
                     Form: "between"
                     Subcategorisation frame: [p'____[ᴅᴘ D' NPᴘʟ]]
```

Many thanks!